# Laravel JsonResource return specific key

Tags: laravel

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class PostResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'description' => $this->description,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        ];
    }
}
```

Sometimes I need to return some specific key instead whole resource.
How to return a specific array of `key` from `JsonResource toArray()`? like `Request` with `only(['key1', 'key4'])` function.

Answer (score 0):

From your controller, when you pass data to your view or API, you simply specify the exact key you want to access.

For example, in your controller

```
public function store(Request $request){

//You other logic here
$post = new PostResource( $request->all() );

//Here, you return only the specific key you want to access
return response([
     'title' => $post->title,
  ]);
}
```

All the best

Comment: yeah, but your answer is just to write what we have written on ```PostResource->toArray()``` method. What I want is to select some key from ```toArray()``` method returns. Just like ```Request::only()``` method so I can just return directly ```PostResource``` with specific keys. Would be nice if I can use ```except()``` method.

Comment: You're right, my method above calls dorectly what we wrote on the Resource. I am not sure if there are helper functions to simply the calling of a specific key. Went though the documentation and  did not find anything concrete. All the best.